# Count the number of rows in database where multiple field is equal to different value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Table **books**:

```
subject  |  userid  |  flag
---------+----------+--------
math     |  abc     |  0
math     |  abc     |  0
english  |  xyz     |  0
```

I wanna search the number of ***math*** subject where ***userid*** and ***flag = 0***.

How should I write the SQL statement?

I tried `COUNT(subject) AS math FROM books WHERE userid = 'abc' AND flag = '0';`

It doesn't work.

Comment: define "It doesn't work."

Comment: Also, what you want isn't very clear.  Your sample query suggests you want to return only rows where `userid='abc'` but in your question you said you want userid and flag=0.  And you suggested you wanted only math subjects, but your query doesn't attempt that.

Comment: I want the number/count of subject where userid and flag field is equal to abc and 0, is that possible?

Comment: @AdamSmith do you also want to filter where `subject = math` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get only the `math` subjects with `userid = 'abc' AND flag = '0'`, you can use below query:

```
SELECT COUNT(subject) AS math 
FROM books WHERE userid = 'abc' AND flag = '0' AND subject = 'math';
```

check out the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b59be/2)

otherwise if you only want subjects with `userid = 'abc' AND flag = '0'`, the `query` given by you is perfectly doing that:

```
SELECT COUNT(subject) AS math 
FROM books WHERE userid = 'abc' AND flag = '0';
```

check out the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b59be/1)

For displaying in `php` using `mysql_fetch_assoc` you can give the column name to access the value like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(subject) AS math 
    FROM books WHERE userid = 'abc' AND flag = '0'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No math subjects exist";
    exit;
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["math"];
}
```

Comment: How to I use php to display the count number? I use mysql_fetch_assoc and it will just display an array math=>4

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
SELECT COUNT(subject) AS math
FROM books 
WHERE flag = '0'
GROUP BY userid
HAVING userid = 'abc';
```